# How does this site deal with aliases?

Tags: discussion, moderators, user-accounts

**How does the site deal with aliases?**

Suppose the moderators are convinced about some accounts being the aliases of one principle account. Will all such alias accounts be  suspended under all circumstances?

Comment: [Sock Puppet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682) accounts will be deleted. If another account from same IP won't upvote main account, it could be co-worker or someone else. In those cases, accounts won't be deleted/suspended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Why are people allowed to have multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72277/260388),

> People are allowed to have multiple accounts **as long as they don't use them to vote for themselves.**

If those accounts are intended to *support each others*<sup>[1]</sup>, they will be deleted or suspended; for example we've recently deleted couple of sock-puppets.

For more information, visit [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/260388).

[1] Some examples:

- Voting on your own posts
- Answering your own questions with the other account(s)
- Casting multiple votes on others' posts
- Supporting your own arguments
- Using bounties to circumvent the rep cap
- Circumventing suspensions, quality bans, or the rate limits on posting questions / answers / comments / etc.

Comment: OK. Now u urself is a MOD. Can u check if someone is actually doing these things? Like voting on one's own posts etc? Can u guys check who is voting what posts?

Comment: @Rickross Mods can't check who voted their posts. But we have different methods to check Sock Puppet accounts.