# Why can't the system auto-handle the issue of unfair voting that happens due to sock puppets like it does in case of serial voting?

Tags: support, voting, user-accounts

In case of serial voting, we know that, the system auto detects and corrects the voting. So, there is nothing to worry about.

But why can't it do the same in cases of the unfair voting that is happening between (or due to) sock puppets (aliases; same user different accounts)?

I myself have asked a question on sock puppets previously here: [How does this site deal with aliases?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/how-does-this-site-deal-with-aliases)

The answer there says it's ok to have multiple accounts but if unfair voting is happening then that might lead to account suspension:

> - **Voting on your own posts**
> - Answering your own questions with the other account(s)
> - **Casting multiple votes on others' posts**
> - Supporting your own arguments
> - Using bounties to circumvent the rep cap
> - Circumventing suspensions, quality bans, or the rate limits on posting questions / answers / comments / etc.

So, assume for keeping things simple, A and B be the sock puppets. I am concerned about the following kinds unfair voting.

1. A upvoting B's posts and B upvoting A's posts.
2. A and B both upvoting (or downvoting) the same posts.

   - My question is why can't system itself detect such cases of unfair voting?
   - What's the guaranty that each time such unfair voting has happened it will be corrected? Because, if not the system, it now depends on moderators' alertness and expertise?

I'm asking this question because I have good suspicion that something like that is happening to my posts on Meta. That is a user and his alias is casting multiple downvotes on my posts and casting upvotes on each other's posts is also happening. Obviously, I can't be 100% sure but I suspect that it's happening.

Regarding the support that I may expect from the CMs, can I, for example, request them through "Contact us" to investigate particular posts where I think unfair voting has happened? Is that a valid request to make?

Comment: This might be complex issue. It could be even multiple users downvoting your posts. Anyways, let me check any suspicious voting on your profile.

Comment: Ok but the main issue is if system auto handles  there is no scope of any error.. @TheDestroyer

Comment: Sock activities will be detected but might take sometime. But it might be bad idea to conclude it too fast. But let us check.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I am not concluding anything. Obviously I can't be 100% sure but I have some suspicion from some time. I just want the system to handle it if that's possible.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Let we Mods check.

Comment: Ok @TheDestroyer I have marked two of my questions clearly now.

Comment: Btw, If you feel confident about something going wrong, you can use "contact us" button and describe the issue to reach out Stack Exchange.

Comment: Well we can't be confident fully but I'm observing keenly something over several months. And, I'm convinced that something is wrong. I can even point out individual posts where I think such voting has happened. If nothing works out then asking the CMs through contact us is certainly an option. @Pandya But what I really want here is the system to handle it. Mods are human beings so they can make mistakes but not the system. So, basically I want a full-proof protection against such unfair voting.